# Search muliple columns for the most common value

Tags: pandas

excuse the basic nature of this question but I have searched for hours for an answer and they all seem to over complicate what I need.

I have a dataframe like the following: -

```
id food_item_1   food_item_2   food_item_3

1  nuts          bread         coffee     
2  potatoes      coffee        cake
3  fish          beer          coffee
4  bread         coffee        coffee
```

What I want to do is search all the 'food_item_*' columns (so in this case there are 3) and have returned back to me the single most common value such as e.g. 'coffee' across all 3 columns.

Could someone please recommend the best way to do this?

Many thanks

md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html), last select first value by position with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
a = df.filter(like='food_item_').stack().mode().iat[0]
print (a)
coffee
```

Another idea is with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and selecting first value of index:

```
a = df.filter(like='food_item_').stack().value_counts().index[0]
```

Comment: thanks for the response @jezrael! The code ```a = df.filter(like='food_word_').stack().mode().iat[0]``` gives me no errors but also returns no data when printing 'a'. If I explicitly add a column name in full such as ```df.filter(like='food_word_1')```, I get data. But the issue with this is I can't seem to be able to get it to consider the 3 columns in the search as I can only define one at a time. I guess there is a technique to get around this?

Comment: I forgot to add that this is the same case for the 2nd code approach (Series.value.counts) so I suspect I am missing a very simple point here

Comment: @micdoher - So what is `print (df.columns)` ? do you need processing all columns, because `id` is index? then use `df.stack().mode().iat[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also `melt` your columns and `value_counts`:

```
print (df.melt(id_vars="id", value_vars=df.columns[1:])["value"].value_counts())

coffee      5
bread       2
nuts        1
potatoes    1
cake        1
beer        1
fish        1
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer and it does nearly everything I needed once I changed the ```value_vars=df.columns[1:]``` to ```value_vars=df.columns[0:]```. One issue it has thrown up is it seems to count the NULL data and therefore presents this at the top of the list. Is there an easy way around this please?

Comment: You can always do a `dropna()` after the melt to get rid of null data.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and I played around with it and couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I eventually went for a more basic approach as my level in Python is currently basic learner but it done the job eventually: - ```          if culprit == '' or culprit == 'coffee':
            culprit=df_food.loc[:,('food_word_1', 'food_word_2', 'food_word_3')].stack().value_counts().index[1]```